# How can I change an icon based on the selected option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```js
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".title").html(value);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="title"> Title </span>
<br /><br />
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a social media</option>
  <option value="Telegram" >Telegram</option>
  <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="GooglePlus">GooglePlus</option>
</select>
```

All I'm trying to do is also changing that icon. I mean I have an array contains needed class names:

```
var classes = {Telegram: "fa-telegram", Instagram: "fa-instagram", Facebook: "fa-facebook-square", GooglePlus: "fa-google-plus-square"};
```

I want to change the class of that `i` *(which is into `span.icon`)* based on the selected option. How can I do that?

Comment: You can do it with pure css.. no need js

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove existing classes on the icon and then set the new classes. This can be done through:

```
// Remove current icon.
$("#socialIcon i").attr("class","");

// Set the new icon.
$("#socialIcon i").addClass("fa");
$("#socialIcon i").addClass(classes[value]);
```

Note that I have added an ID "socialIcon" on the span wrapping the icon in order to be able to uniquely identify it.

```js
var classes = {Telegram: "fa-telegram", Instagram: "fa-instagram", Facebook: "fa-facebook-square", GooglePlus: "fa-google-plus-square"};


$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".title").html(value);
  
  // Remove current icon.
  $("#socialIcon i").attr("class","");
  
  // Set the new icon.
  $("#socialIcon i").addClass("fa").addClass(classes[value]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<span id="socialIcon" class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="title"> Title </span>
<br /><br />
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a social media</option>
  <option value="Telegram" >Telegram</option>
  <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="GooglePlus">GooglePlus</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Just one thing, isn't `span.icon` unique enough?

Comment: No, that would apply to all `span.icon` you have on the page. So you should either have a unique class to select this particular icon or a class that is only set on this icon. Though the latter is only useful when you have some sort of framework that might change the ID of elements at rendering - which is something that applies to ASP.Net sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$.prop()` instead as you need to reset entire icon set.

```js
var classes = {
  Telegram: "fa-telegram",
  Instagram: "fa-instagram",
  Facebook: "fa-facebook-square",
  GooglePlus: "fa-google-plus-square"
};
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".title").html(value);
  $('.icon').find('i').prop('class', 'fa ' + classes[value]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span class="title"> Title </span>
<br /><br />
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a social media</option>
  <option value="Telegram" >Telegram</option>
  <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
  <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
  <option value="GooglePlus">GooglePlus</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Might this helps

```
 var classes = {Telegram: "fa-telegram", Instagram: "fa-instagram", Facebook: "fa-facebook-square", GooglePlus: "fa-google-plus-square"};
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
   var value = $(this).val();
   var icon = classes[value];
   $('span.icon').find('i').attr('class', '');
   $('span.icon').find('i').addClass('fa '+classes[value]);
   $(".title").html(value);
});
```

Comment: FWIW; You can simply add the `i` to your selector query instead of  performing another search: `$('span.icon i')`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.icon i.fa').removeClass(Object.values(classes).reduce((out, it) => { return out + ' ' + it}, '') + ' fa-check-square');

$('.icon i.fa').addClass(classes[value]);
```

https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this.

```
var classes = 
{Telegram: "fa-telegram", Instagram: "fa-instagram", Facebook: "fa-facebook-square", GooglePlus: "fa-google-plus-square"};


$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".title").html(value);  
  $("#socialIcon i").attr("class","fa "+classes[value]);
});
```